# mysql_user modue is showing error when running in centos7

Tags: ansible

When running mysql_user module in ansible it is showing the below error.

**ansible** version - 2.6

**mysql** version - 5.6

yaml syntax :-

```
- name: Test | mysql

  mysql_user: name=test password=test host=localhost state=present
```

error :-

```
fatal: [xx.xx.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to xx.xx.xx.xx closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_73s74m/ansible_module_mysql_user.py\", line 206, in <module>\r\n    from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule\r\nzlib.error: Error -2 while preparing to decompress data: inconsistent stream state\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
    "rc": 1
}
```

Comment: I just had the same problem, found it be problem with my installed ansible version which was 2.4.2. The issue got fixed when I upgraded ansible version to 2.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got **Ansible 2.6.2**, **Python 2.7.12** and **MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.42**.

This sorted the issue for me.

On the server:

> 1 Download the version of zlib that we want to update to
>
> > `wget https://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz`
>
> 2 Unpack the source
>
> > `tar -xzf zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz`
>
> 3 Get into the source
>
> > `cd zlib-1.2.11/`
>
> 4 Configure it Executing the next command. The prefix "/usr" is used
>   to configure the library under this path, usually at the end it will
>   be within "/usr/lib"
>
> > `./configure --shared --prefix=/usr`
>
> 5 Execute the "make" command
>
> > `make`
>
> 6 Execute the "make install" command
>
> > `make install`
>
> 7 Check symbolic links on /usr/lib
>
> > `cd /usr/lib`
> >
> > `ls -l libz*`

**Sample Output**

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 147170 Nov  8 01:20 libz.a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     24 Nov  8 01:21 libz.so -> ../../lib/libz.so.1.2.11 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     14 Nov  8 01:20 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 117592 Nov  8 01:20 libz.so.1.2.11
```

After this procedure I executed the recipe again and it worked

This was found [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/47927)

Answer (score 0):

**Error info**

```
fatal: [112.35.1.76]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 112.35.1.76 closed.\r\n",  "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_BNXyN9/ansible_module_mysql_variables.py\", line 60, in <module>\r\n    from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule\r\nzlib.error: Error -2 while preparing to decompress data: inconsistent stream state\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}
```

**Ansible info**

```
[root@f8830824d94e test_playbookyml]# ansible --version
ansible 2.6.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.5 (default, Apr 10 2018, 17:08:37) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)]
```

**Resolve**

I get the same error today.When I change the params ansible_python_interpreter of 112.35.1.76 to "/usr/bin/python3.6" in my ansible hosts, it works. My ansible server's python version is python3.6 too. Maybe it can help you.